# Connecting to hosted MySQL server with Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've been recently trying to connect to a hosted MySQL using Java but can't get it to work. I can connect to a local MySQL with `localhost` using:

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lego?"
                + "user=******&password=*******");
```

(Replacing the astrisks withmy username and password)

I can connect to the hosted MySQL database fine with PHP using:

```
mysql_connect('mysql.hosts.co.uk','******','**********');
mysql_select_db('test');
```

My problem is, I cannot connect via Java. I have an Exception which is caught if the connection doesn't work and this is always printed out.

Any ideas why it isn't working? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your time,

InfinitiFizz

Comment: Can you connect to the server via another mysql client such as the mysql query browser?

How about with another user?

Comment: Please show the exception as well as the connection string you use (with username/password replaced).

Comment: I find Squirrel a very handy tool for testing database connections, as it is written in java and hence uses the same connectors you use in your program. Often it's just an error in the connection string

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Replace `catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Something failed"); }` by `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` or just `catch (Exception e) { throw e; }` and update your question to include the valuable information you got instead. It tells something about the cause of the problem. You know, once the cause is *understood*, the solution is obvious ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it works in php (i guess you didn't try to connect from a local place with php???) it shouldn't be a port problem... but you should check that port 3306 is open... and ask the hosts company about that.

Have you noticed that in the DriverManager
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html
you have:
getConnection(String url) 
but also:
getConnection(String url, String user, String password)

Perhaps it would work better...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to select a non-standard port, since I'd imagine the hosting server is serving lots of MySQL instances and they can't all use the normal one. I don't see selection of a port here.

If that's not it, perhaps there is a firewall issue somewhere along the way that's blocking the port or connection.